# Does IE 7 support the content pseudo-class?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am generating pipes in my list using pseudo-classes and it works fine except they are not being rendered in IE 7.  The code looks like:

```
.brandLinks a:after {
margin: 0 4px;
content: "|";
}

.brandLinks a:last-child:after {
content: " "
}
```

Is this just something IE 7 does not do or is my code wonky?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, IE7 doesn't support this.

See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/content.html and 
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter_content.html for a detailed comparison.

Furthermore, an interesting opinion to take into consideration ;-)

> I feel that we shouldn't use the
>   content declaration at all. It adds
>   content to the page, and CSS is meant
>   for adding presentation to the page,
>   and not content. Therefore I feel that
>   you should use JavaScript if you want
>   to dynamically generate content. CSS
>   is the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: it is fine to generate content that's used specifically for the sake of presentation.

Comment: IE7 simply doesn't support it. The existance of some ugly workaround doesn't change the facts.

Answer (score 3):

This works on IE7.

```
.brandLinks a {zoom: expression( this.runtimeStyle.zoom="1", this.insertBefore( document.createElement("i"), this.firstChild ).className="ie-before" );}

.brandLinks a .ie-before {zoom: expression(this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = '1', this.innerHTML = '|');}
```

​

Comment: This works in ie7, I am just curious to know why it doesn't in IE8 or 9 ? is it because css expressions are dropped in ie8 and later, not sure...

Comment: Dynamic Properties a.k.a. CSS Expressions were [introduced in IE5 and dropped for IE8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

CSS might be for presentation only, but in cases like when you need to clear your floats, it's very useful, too bad the famous 'clearfix' doesn't work correctly in old browers. Maybe it could be implemented with a different approach other than merely content manipulation... there are some javascripts you can find on googlecode that make old ie's support many selectors it didn't before, but not sure about pseudoclasses... might be useful

http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/